# React-native expo application not working on fetch api any one have solution for expo applications

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, fetch, expo

I have created one Expo application and it has been working for 6
months.  Now when I am updating my react-native library then I found
one error in  Fetch API Call here is an error :

> DEALER_ERROR TypeError: Network request failed at
>   XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror
>   (D:\greensawari\GreensawariApplicationuserside\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\core\whatwg-fetch.js:504)
>   at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent
>   (D:\greensawari\GreensawariApplicationuserside\node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172)
>   at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState
>   (D:\greensawari\GreensawariApplicationuserside\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:580)
>   at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse
>   (D:\greensawari\GreensawariApplicationuserside\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:394)
>   at
>   D:\greensawari\GreensawariApplicationuserside\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:507
>   at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit
>   (D:\greensawari\GreensawariApplicationuserside\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189)
>   at MessageQueue.__callFunction
>   (D:\greensawari\GreensawariApplicationuserside\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:366)
>   at
>   D:\greensawari\GreensawariApplicationuserside\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:106
>   at MessageQueue.__guard
>   (D:\greensawari\GreensawariApplicationuserside\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314)
>   at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>   (D:\greensawari\GreensawariApplicationuserside\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:105)

Rveryone facing an issue and they will try to resolve it  but my problem is that I am using a react-native-expo  so inside expo app, I don't have an android manifest file  so how can I put my Network code  inside the expo application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.2.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.3.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">dev.local</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**here is fetch api call**

```
fetch('https://xyzxyzxyz.com')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson.movies;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```